# Pipe output to getArgs in Haskell

Tags: bash, haskell, functional-programming, command-line-arguments

Today I was trying to make a program in which the contents from a file would be read as the input of a Haskell program like this:

```
module Main where

import System.Posix.Env.ByteString (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  info <- getArgs
  print info
```

It works if I send (Byte)strings directly like this:

```
> runhaskell Main.hs example
  ["example"]
```

However, if I try to "pipe" the output of one command to this program I get an empty response, as follows:

```
> echo example | runhaskell Main.hs 
  []
```

Even if I compile the program, use the string version of getArgs, mark with special bash variables like $! or alike. The only way I have found is to do like this:

```
> runhaskell Main.hs $(echo example)
  ["example"]
```

Which is not the intention and "piping" several commands makes it sort of annoying.

Does anyone has an improved version or reason why "getArgs" does not work with pipes??

Thanks

Comment: Pipe pipes to stdin.

Comment: Nothing special about your program; `echo example` prints `example`; but `echo example | echo` prints nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Piping works by setting the standard output of one command to the standard input of another. It doesn't do anything with arguments. If you want to retrieve all of the standard input as a `ByteString`, use [`getContents`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:getContents) from `Data.ByteString`.

Comment: You are completely right, I tried using ```getContents``` and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the content you're piping to the second process to be passed
as arguments rather than on stdin you can use `xargs` like so:

```
echo example | xargs runhaskell Main.hs
```

Comment: This is the right solution I was looking for, along with the one 4casle proposes, I will update the code accordingly. Thanks @gallais